# Problems with advanced search using button

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make an advance search like the usual search on the nav bar, but this time I wanna make it like a filter using buttons that seems like links but the problem is that when I click the button it does make a good search and it told me that theres is nothing with the value of 1000 but in my DB there are colums with that value (int)

I don´t want to use another lenguage, i just wanna try with PHP

the value that show in my URL are

> http://localhost/talvez%20usuario/1000more.php?valor=1000&send=1%2C000

this is my code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    require 'extras/config.php';
    require 'functions.php';

    comprobarSession();

    $conexion = conexion($bd_config);
    if (!$conexion) {
        header('Location: error.php');
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && !empty($_GET['valor'])) {
        $busqueda = limpiarDatos($_GET['valor']);

        $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM publications WHERE salario LIKE >= 1000-500 and salario <= 1000+500');

        $statement->execute(array(':valor' => "%$busqueda%"));
        $resultados = $statement->fetchAll();

        if(empty($resultados)) {
            $titulo = 'No se encontraron articulos con el resultado '. $busqueda;
        } else {
            $titulo = 'Resultados de la busqueda: ' . $busqueda;
        }
    } 

    require 'views/1000more.php';

?>
```

and this is my button:

```
<form action="1000more.php" method="GET">
   <input type="hidden" value="1000" name="valor" />
   $<input type="submit" class="btn btn-link" name="send" value="1,000">+</input>(16947)
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the "valor" in where statement :

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM publications WHERE valor = :valor and salario >= 1000-500 and salario <= 1000+500');
```

And Edit that line also :

```
$statement->execute(array(':valor' => $busqueda));
```

Comment: hm... it doesn't work, they don't bring me anything from the DB with value equal than 1000 or less or equal than 1000

Comment: Edit that also : $statement->execute(array(':valor' => $busqueda));

Comment: yes, I fix it, now the problem is when I change of page, the variable on the URL get lost and they don't show me the result, but I'm thinking in fix that whit a infint scroll ;), thanks for your support!!